# Desktop shortcut to a specific profile in Windows Terminal

Tags: shortcuts, windows-11, windows-terminal

I have a few custom profiles in Windows Terminal, as shown in the settings menu:

[image: custom profiles]

How do I make a desktop shortcut which I can double click that launches windows terminal with one of these profiles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```bsh
wt new-tab --profile "Spyder (Spy)"
```

works :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Try,

`wt -h` which gives you the command line options.  However, the answer by Greedo still doesn't find it, its buried deeper.
`wt nt -h` will get the new-tab options.  There is a help for each of the 'Subcommands'.  Most all the *subcommands* have a two letter shortcut.  `Split-Pane` =  `sp`, `focus-tab` is `ft` and so on.

In general, windows terminal borrows from powershell syntax,  e.g. `verb-noun` though its internally inconsistent, but consistent with linux at least in that the options are given by `--focus, -f` where two hyphens mark a *fullname* option and one `-` marks a short option.